# JavaScript / jQuery date picker that allows both inclusive and exclusive ranges?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, daterangepicker

I've been looking around at a few js/jQuery date range pickers for a project.

So far I haven't found any which specifically claim to be for only inclusive or exclusive date ranges, or what I'd really like, which allows me to set whether a range will be inclusive or exclusive.

- Inclusive date ranges start on the first day, and include the final day. These are useful for vacations for instance. I have ten days off and I want to indicate exactly those ten days on the widget.
- Exclusive date ranges start on the first day, and are over on the final day. That is, the final day is not included. It is the first day not in the range. These are useful for bookings and reservations. I have a booking to check in to a hotel on January 7 and check out on January 19. I will not be staying on the checkout day, but when I think about my reservation I think of the check out date, not the final date I stay overnight.

Is there a JavaScript or jQuery date picker which supports both concepts?

Answer (score 1):

I didnt find too. But I customized the datepicker from jquery - you need to handle the [beforeShowDay](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Datepicker#event-beforeShowDay) event; all you have to do is to verify if that day is in your range and return a meaningful css class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the datepicker's job to handle that. A range is a range is a range. Take it, then handle the end date inclusively or exclusively when you're using it (e.g., when passing it to a database query).

Comment: A range is a range yes, but a visualization is not a visualization. It would make sense to be able to display a checkout date specifically in a way not necessary for inclusive ranges. It could also make sense to provide a getter / setter for both to make the code using it natural and more easily avoid off-by-one errors. And of course most existing pickers will have been created with one of the two possibilities in mind anyway without stating so clearly in their documentation.